# Name of pi in indian mathematics

Tags: mathematics

What name did Aryabhata and Bhaskara or Madhava gave to the well known number pi (of approximate value 3.14159)? How was it referred to?

Or was it given a long description  as the " ratio of arc length of perimeter and diameter" of a circle?

They did not call it *pi*, the name  we know is of Greek origin (Archimedes), may be the *perimeter* length of a circle diameter unity.

Comment: Most of the references are indirect, they specify the circumference and radius and people calculate the value of pi from there. For a reference you can look at this paper https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-13-1229-8_11

Comment: afaik, they don't give a name for it in śāstras. \pi is a ratio like golden ratio, you just need to state the ratio, name is irrelevant for it.